# Pandas Efficient Filtering: Same filter condition on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

Say I have the data below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 1],
                   'col2': [2, 4, 3],
                   'col3': [3, 6, 5],
                   'col4': [4, 8, 7]})
```

Is there a way to use list comprehensions to filter data efficiently? For example, if I wanted to find all cases where col2 was even OR col3 was even OR col 4 was even, is there a simpler way than just writing this?

`df[(df['col2'] % 2 == 0) | (df['col3'] % 2 == 0) | (df['col4'] % 2 == 0)]`

It would be nice if I could pass in a list of columns and the condition to check.

Answer (score 9):

`df[(df[cols] % 2 == 0).any(axis=1)]`

where `cols` is your list of columns

Comment: I like this answer. This is an easy way to get the list of columns. `df[(df[df.columns] % 2 == 0).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Though for the sake of the example problem's question, it would be
`df[(df[cols] % 2 == 0).any(axis=1)]`